REFPROP 9 - Possible irregularities in organic fluid state properties
I am currently designing a Organic Rankine cycle-based turbine with Toluene at its working fluid. At the beginning of the expansion the fluid pressure $p_0$ is 2 MPa and temperature $T_0$ is 550 K. After the expansion, the pressure $p_2$ is 0.03 MPa and temperaure $T_2$ is 460.15 K. I am using REFPROP 9 to calculate the fluid parameters in various points of the cycle, with its T,s diagram displayed in the figure below.

The expansion process in full involves the working fluid in the superheated state. According to REFPROP 9, the constant pressure heat capacities are $C_{p0} = 2.4085$ KJ/kgK and $C_{p2} = 1.7298$ KJ/kgK; the constant volume heat capacities are $C_{v0} = 2.0071$ KJ/kgK and $C_{v2} = 1.6368$ KJ/kgK;heat capacity ratios are $k_0 = C_{p0}/C_{v0} = 1.2$ and $k_2 = C_{p2}/C_{v2} = 1.0568$; and local sound speeds are $c_{s1} = 164.62$ m/s and $c_{s2} = 208.18$ m/s.
The specific gas constant for Toluene should be $R(Tol) = R/M = 8314/92,138 = 90.23$ J/kgK. However, when the following formula is used to determine gas consants:
$$
C_p = kR/(k-1) → R = C_p (k-1)/k,
$$
using the data from REFPROP, $R_0 = 2408.5(1.2-1)/1.2 = 401.42$ J/kgK, which is absurdly large, and $R_2 = 1729.8(1.0568-1)/1.0568 = 92.97$ J/kgK, which is somewhat similar to the capacity found via Toluene's molar mass.
If calculated via Mayer's equation (in KJ/kgK):
$$
R_0 = C_{p0} - C_{v0} = 2.4805 - 2.0071 = 0.4734;
$$
$$
R_2 = C_{p2} - C_{v2} = 1.7298 - 1.6368 = 0.093;
$$
the staring gas constant is still over 5 times higher than the gas constant at the end of the expanion and the gas constant calculated via molar mass.
Local sound speeds can be calculated as such:
$$
C_s = \sqrt{kRT}.
$$
If the formula above is used, then the speeds of sounds calculated with the gas constants calculated via molar mass, via heat ratios and via Mayer's equation respectively will be as follows (in m/s):
$$
C_{s0(M)} = \sqrt{k_0R_{M}T_0}=\sqrt{1.2\bullet 90.23\bullet 550}=244.03;
$$
$$
C_{s2(M)} = \sqrt{k_2R_{M}T_2}=\sqrt{1.0568\bullet 90.23\bullet 460.15}=209.47;
$$
$$
C_{s0(k)} = \sqrt{k_0R_{k_0}T_0}=\sqrt{1.2\bullet 401.42\bullet 550}=514.72;
$$
$$
C_{s2(k)} = \sqrt{k_2R_{k_2}T_2}=\sqrt{1.0568\bullet 92.97\bullet 460.15}=212.63;
$$
$$
C_{s0(Mayer)} = \sqrt{k_0R_{Mayer_0}T_0}=\sqrt{1.2\bullet 473.4\bullet 550}=558.97;
$$
$$
C_{s2(Mayer)} = \sqrt{k_2R_{Mayer_2}T_2}=\sqrt{1.0568\bullet 93\bullet 460.15}=212.66.
$$
However, according to REFFPROP, the sound speeds are $S_{s0}=164,62$ m/s and $S_{s2}=208,18$ m/s, meaning the speed is lower before the expansion than after.
What could be the reason for those disperancies? I don't want to fault REFPROP, but I have no answer to explain this situation.
The specified points data from REFPROP is in the figure below.

